# postgres - how update an item of jsonb list by date

Tags: arrays, postgresql, jsonb

I have a table.

```
create table tb(
  userid int,
  nodes jsonb)
```

nodes sample:

```
{
 "weight": [{"date":"<date>", value: 50}, {"date":"<date>", value: 60}],
 "height": [{"date":"<date>", value: 170}, {"date":"<date>", value: 172}],
}
```

I want to change the weight of a date in the list of weights.

Or enter a new value in the height list on a specific date. What should I do?

I wrote this. but it is add a new item only.

```
INSERT INTO tb (UserId, Nodes)
values (1, '{"weight": [{"value":"50","date":"2021-07-24 18:17:33.000"}]}')
ON CONFLICT (UserId) DO UPDATE
    SET Nodes = jsonb_set(tb.Nodes, '{"weight"}',
                          tb.Nodes->'weight' || '{"value":"50","date":"2021-07-24 18:17:43.000"}');
```

I need to edit a value for a specific date.

Comment: Have you considered normalising your database schema instead of storing JSON?

Comment: "*enter a new value in the height list on a specific date*" - your current code does that already, no?

Comment: No, really, this is not just my data. I wrote this for simplicity. Each user has specific information that is not the same, but all have a date field.

Comment: No, I have to search between dates and edit any that have a specific date, regardless of the time

Comment: You mean you want to append a new value for a date, but if an entry with that date already exists, it should be overwritten? I.e. you don't know when you need to update vs when you need to insert? Because the insertion part already works in the code you have.

Comment: Do you care about the order in that array?

Answer (score 0):

I self wrote this.

```
BEGIN;
LOCK TABLE "UserFitnessData" IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;

do $$
    declare today date;
    declare r jsonb; -- RECORD
    declare idx int :=0;

    begin
        INSERT INTO "UserFitnessData" (UserId, Nodes)
        values (1, '{"FrontImage": [{"value":"50","date":"2021-07-28 18:17:33.000"}]}');
    EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN
        today := '2021-07-25 18:17:33.000'::date;
        raise notice 'exep >>> %', today;

        FOR r IN
            SELECT jsonb_array_elements(Nodes->'FrontImage') arr FROM "UserFitnessData" WHERE userid = 1
            LOOP
                if (r->>'date')::date = today then
                    
                    UPDATE "UserFitnessData"
                    SET Nodes = Nodes #- FORMAT('{"FrontImage", %s}', idx)::text[] WHERE userid = 1;

                    idx := idx-1;

                    UPDATE "UserFitnessData"
                    SET Nodes = jsonb_set("UserFitnessData".Nodes, '{"FrontImage"}',
                                          "UserFitnessData".Nodes->'FrontImage' || '{"value":"1245","date":"2021-07-27 18:17:43.000"}');
                end if;
                idx := idx+1;
               

        END LOOP;
        RETURN;
    end $$;

COMMIT;
```

This is what started me right now. If anyone has a shorter solution, tell me.